# How to insert data in linked structure

Tags: c

My insertion worked, so a new question, How do I set a data to NULL in C? Pls see the last part for illustration.!

I have defined a structure type

```
typedef struct node {
    char* data;
    int weight;
    bool  end_of_key;
    struct node * left;
    struct node * equal;
    struct node * right;
} node_t;



int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
node_t* root=NULL;
int weight;
int i = 1;

insert(root,"cat",3);
insert(root,"at",2);
insert(root,"cute",4);
.....
return 0 ;}
```

This is my insert function

```
node_t*  insert(node_t* pNode,char* word, int weight) {

    /**
    * Create a new pNode, and save a character from word
    */
  pNode = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));

if(*pNode->data == NULL){   
        pNode->left = NULL;
        pNode->equal = NULL;
        pNode->right = NULL;
        pNode->data = word;
  }



if (word[0] < *(pNode->data)) {
    /**
    * Insert the character on the left branch
    */
    pNode->left = insert(pNode, word, weight);
}

else if (word[0] == *(pNode->data)) {
    if ((word[1]) == '\0') {
        /**
        *set pNode end_of_key_flag to true and assign weight
        */
        pNode->end_of_key = true;
        pNode->weight = weight;
    //  printf("%c", *(pNode->data++));
    }
    else {
        /**
        * If the word contains more characters, try to insert them
        * under the equal branch
        */
    //  printf("%c", *(pNode->data++));
        pNode->equal = insert(pNode,word + 1, weight);

    }
}

else {
    /**
    * If current char in word is greater than char in pData
    * Insert the character on the right branch
    */
    pNode->right = insert(pNode,word, weight);
}

return pNode;}
```

this code is trying to do this [image]

So my insertion finally worked but it appears that it can only insert one thing,I am wondering how do I set data to NULL in C?

```
if(*pNode->data == NULL){   
        pNode->left = NULL;
        pNode->equal = NULL;
        pNode->right = NULL;
        pNode->data = word;
  }
```

I want to run this four lines of code when *pNode->data is empty but it apparently did not work the way I wanted it to.

Comment: I don't know, but there's at least one big issue `pNode` isn't modified outside your `insert` function.

Comment: Also: you cannot make a `char *` out of a `const char *`. Probably explains the "address out of bounds" for the string parameter.

Comment: while you're at it, can you show us the exact line where the SEGV occurs (congrats for actually _using_ a debugger in a SO question, that said)

Comment: also I don't get why you're trying to insert `c` by passing `"cat"`

Comment: 2 hours ago you asked this: [initializing linked structure node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46031645/initializing-linked-structure-node). Your problems originating from the fact that you have to get a basic understanding of C, especially pointers, C-strings and arrays. I don't want to offend you take the following as an advice: **Learn C properly instead of asking about each problem, you will benefit from it and gain understanding. You will not learn if we fix your code and you don't understand. Learn and fix yourself and try to understand.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [initializing linked structure node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46031645/initializing-linked-structure-node)

Comment: @Andre Kampling
I tried ur method when I changed char* data to char data and 
I used pNode->data = word[0]
it shows this error I dont know why :(

Comment: @Michael Walz
I also tried to allocate memory for pNode->data using
pNode->data = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
but it still didnt work out

Comment: @VincentZhou what are you _actually_  trying to achieve? Please read this: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @leyanpan
It returns pNode, and I want to get the data stored in pNode->data

Comment: @VincentZhou: Read my comment again and **learn the basic C concepts**. StackOverflow [has a C book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre
sorry I tried using pNode->data = word[0], does this allow me to insert 'c'? but it shows the same error

Comment: why your linked list contains nodes `left`, `right` and `equal`. what is the logic of filling this list up?

Comment: Can you confirm that each node contains only one single `char`? What do the nodes `TI2`, `RI2` actually contain? vadim_hr's comment still stands. Explain more.

Comment: @ Michael Walz  @ vadim_hr
pNode->data contains one charcater, 2 stands for the weight contained at pNode->weight which is the number of characters of a word.
Im trying to do a ternary serch tree,
so here I insert words in the order "cut","at","cute","cure","cat","car","pet"
the first line is just the first character of the word.second line is the second character of the word
and if it is smaller, go to the left, for example here ,"a" goes to the left of "c", and "p" goes to the right of "c"

Comment: There are many issues within your code. You should learn how to use a debugger. Problems spotted: `if ((word + 1) == '\0')`-> `if ((word[1]) == '\0')`, `insert(root, xxx, 3);` -> `root = insert(root, xxx, 3);`, `insert` won't modify the `root` parameter. And you don't initialize `weight` and `end_of_key` in all cases. There are probably more problems.

Comment: @Michael Walz 
Thanks a lot ,can u elaborate what do u mean insert won't modify the root parameter?

Comment: `root = NULL; insert(root, xxx, 3); `; now root will still be `NULL`, parameters are passed by valuen in C. This is absolutely basic C knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Some improvements of your code

- `insert()` must have first parameter to be `node_t **` (see comments)
- `char *data` must be `char data`, because every node contains only one char
- `weight` can be calculated when the list is filled up

Here is corrected version of your code. Function `get()` is used to find the key in the filled up list (for testing).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node {
    char data;
    int weight;
    struct node * left;
    struct node * equal;
    struct node * right;
} node_t;

void insert(node_t** pNode, char* word, int weight)
{
    char data;
    node_t **pNext;
    node_t *pCurrent;

    if (word == NULL)
    {
        return ;
    }

    data = word[weight];

    if (*pNode == NULL)
    {
        *pNode = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        pCurrent = *pNode;
        memset(pCurrent, 0, sizeof(node_t));
        pCurrent->data = data;
    }
    else
    {
        pCurrent = *pNode;
    }

    if (data == pCurrent->data)
    {
        weight ++;
        if (strlen(word) == weight)
        {
            pCurrent->weight = weight;
            return;
        }

        pNext = &pCurrent->equal;
    }
    else if (data > pCurrent->data)
    {
        pNext = &pCurrent->right;
    }
    else
    {
        pNext = &pCurrent->left;
    }

    insert(pNext, word, weight);
}

int get(node_t** pNode, char *word, int weight)
{
    char data;
    node_t **pNext;
    node_t *pCurrent;

    if (word == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    data = word[weight];

    if (*pNode == NULL)
    {
        return 0; // not found
    }

    pCurrent = *pNode;

    if (data == pCurrent->data)
    {
        weight ++;

        if (strlen(word) == weight)
        {
            return pCurrent->weight;
        }

        pNext = &pCurrent->equal;
    }
    else if (data > pCurrent->data)
    {
        pNext = &pCurrent->right;
    }
    else
    {
        pNext = &pCurrent->left;
    }

    return get(pNext, word, weight);
}

int main()
{
    node_t * root = NULL;

    insert(&root, "cat", 0);
    insert(&root, "at", 0);
    insert(&root, "cute", 0);

    printf("cat=%d\n",get(&root,"cat",0)); // cat=3
    printf("at=%d\n",get(&root,"at",0)); // at=2
    printf("cute=%d\n",get(&root,"cute",0)); // cute=4

    // todo: free memory

    return 0;
}
```

The code is tested except freeing the memory.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is something wrong with your `insert()` signature
(as already pointed by @MichaelWalz )

you'd rather

```
node_t* insert(node_t** pNode, char* word, int weight);
```

and then

```
insert(&root,"cute",4);
```

why don't you start fixing this and edit your post ?